# Using AutoMapper with EF Code First joins whilst sharing mappings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Given the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 Foo_PK { get; set; }
    public String SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
public class Bar
{
    public Int32 Bar_PK { get; set; }
    public Int32 Foo_FK { get; set; }
    public String SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
public class JoinResult<TEntity, TJoiningEntity>
{
    public TEntity From { get; private set; }
    public TEntity To { get; private set; }
    public JoinResult(TEntity from, TEntity to)
    {
        this.From = from;
        this.To = to;
    }
}
public interface IFooResult
{
    public String SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
public interface IBarResult : IFooResult
{
    public String SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
public class FooResultDTO : IFooResult, IBarResult
{
    public String SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public String SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The idea behind this is that we some method of dispensing foo's and foo's with other related records, e.g. if there are 4 bar's then 4 rows in a table with the additional fields.

```
public class FooDispensary
{
    public IQueryable<T> Dispense<T>()
    where T: IFooResult
    {
        using (var repository = new Repository())
        {
            // TODO: Handle mapping for Foo -> FooResult

            // Project to
            return repository.Foos.ProjectTo<FooResultDTO>();
        }
    } 
    public IQueryable<T> DispenseWithBars<T>()
    where T : IFooResult, IBarResult
    {
        using (var repository = new Repository())
        {
            // TODO: Handle mapping for JoinResult.From (same as Foo -> FooResult) as well as to JoinResult.To

            // Project to
            return repository.Foos.Join((f) => f.Foo_PK,
                                        (b) => b.Foo_FK,
                                        (f, b) => new JoinResult<Foo, Bar>(f, b))
                                   .ProjectTo<FooResultDTO>();
        }
    } 
}
```

However, I would ideally like to only specify the base mapping once (Foo -> IFooResult) and then re-use this in the methods where we need to join to a child table.

There are multiple reasons behind wanting to do this which are specific to my project however no need to go into them, I am just wondering if this is possible as I have struggled with the syntax thus far?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map between `Foo` and `FooResult`.  Because the Property `SomeProperty` is named the same in both the source and target Automapper will be able to figure out the mapping implicitly.

```
// TODO: Handle mapping for Foo -> FooResult
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooResult>();
```

Then create a map between `JoinResult<Foo, Bar>` and `FooResultDTO`

```
// TODO: Handle mapping for JoinResult.From (same as Foo -> FooResult) as well as to JoinResult.To
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<JoinResult<Foo, Bar>, FooResultDTO>()
     .ForMember(r => r.SomeProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.From.SomeProperty)
     .ForMember(r => r.SomeOtherProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.To.SomeOtherProperty)
```

> However, I would ideally like to only specify the base mapping once (Foo -> IFooResult) and then re-use this in the methods where we need to join to a child table.

You're not resusing the mapping between `Foo` and `IFooResult` anywhere in your example.  Your second function needs to map between `JoinResult<Foo, Bar>` and `FooResultDTO` as shown above.  If you need to reuse mappings I suggest you look into using an AutoMapper Profile and managing a singleton AutoMapper instance that can be shared between your functions: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration

Comment: Thanks for reply, my point here is that although I am mapping *from* `JoinResult<Foo, Bar>` the mapping between Foo (`(r) => r.From`) and `IFooResult` will remain the same, therefore I would like to re-use this if I can.

Keep in mind that the above is only a simple example for the purposes of keeping the question such that it's easy to understand, there could be 10's of properties on the base class all being mapped from different locations.

Comment: @LukeHennerley I understand what you are asking, but I'm not sure it's possible because of your use of `JoinResult<>`  One possibility you might try is to pull the Foo's back first projecting them to the DTO and then query the Bars and project them to the DTO.  This would allow you to reuse the mappings defined before, but obviously at the cost of query efficiency.

Comment: @LukeHennerley Sorry I can't be of more help.  I'd pose the question on the Automapper forum.  You might get a better reply there:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/automapper-users